# Map<String, List<Sobject>> reference inside apex method

Tags: apex, controller, map

I've a Map getter

```
Map<String,List<Call2_vod__c>> mapProductEntity ; 
for(Account p: [SELECT  Name, (Select call_date_vod__C,signature_vod__c FROM Call2_vod__r  from Account WHERE ID IN : s  ]) {
    mapProductEntity.put(p.Name, p.Call2_vod__r); 
}

return mapProductEntity;
```

I want another method that will fetch map.call2_vod__r.signature. please provide me technical details

Comment: Does this help? https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_maps_lists.htm

Comment: yes, that definitely helps , but here i want map to be referenced inside the controller, from another method not in visualforce page.

Comment: you can do 2 things, 1 create a void method that does the work from the other function and then create just the getter method that returns after. So void fucntion does the loading of the map and then just do public Map<String,List<Call2_vod__c>> getFoo() {return map;} - and that will allow you to put it on the VF page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the value in the map you can access the values via the Map KEY

```
Call2_vod__c[] recs = mapProductEntity.get(*KEYNAME*);
```

The do what you wish with the values.

To get a specific record/field you will have to parse through the list to get the record you want